# How to inherit properties in custom JavaFX panes

Tags: inheritance, javafx, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I want to make a few subclasses of JavaFX's AnchorPane component but in each case inherit AnchorPane's layout features. I am able to define a subclass:

```
package tuto;

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class TutoPane extends javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane {

    protected void layoutChildren() {
        super.layoutChildren();
    }

}
```

... and interestingly I am also able to import this into Scene Builder. However, Scene Builder is not recognizing the inheritance relationship. If I place a normal AnchorPane next to one of my custom TutoPanes in Scene Builder I get this:

[image: showing component in AchorPane]

As you can see, the control placed inside of the AnchorPane (green) has positioning defined by the four Anchor Pane constraints.

However when I try with the TutoPane I get this:

[image: showing component in custom pane]

The control placed inside the TutoPane (dark slate blue) is stuck in the top left corner and the "layout" properties do not give me the four AnchorPane constraints, which I'd expect to find available due to inheritance. What do I need to do to get Scene Builder to recognize my custom pane as an AnchorPane? Is there an equivalent of the JavaBeans Specification that applies to JavaFX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of desperation I took a look at the [source code for the Scene Builder product](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/downloads) and I've taken a look at the stuff that is going on behind the "scene" there.

The authors have hard-coded it to detect properties based on a combination of the class name and property name. The `AnchorPaneConstraintsEditor` is a hard-coded layout and detecting if it needs to be displayed is dependent on the editor finding `Editor.topAnchorPropName`, `Editor.rightAnchorPropName`, `Editor.bottomAnchorPropName`, and `Editor.leftAnchorPropName` in the parent component. These are constants defined in the Editor class:

```
public static final String topAnchorPropName = "AnchorPane.topAnchor";
public static final String rightAnchorPropName = "AnchorPane.rightAnchor";
public static final String bottomAnchorPropName = "AnchorPane.bottomAnchor";
public static final String leftAnchorPropName = "AnchorPane.leftAnchor";
```

Needless to say this design works against specialization and violates a number of basic fundamentals from the JavaBeans specification regarding component introspection.

It also makes subclassing AnchorPane and inheriting its layout constraints completely impossible. It appears there is no solution. If anyone else knows of a way, I invite you to share.

Answer (score 0):

SceneBuilder doesn't show the Anchor constraint field in its properties palette. Add the anchor constraints in the fxml because inherited anchor pane class is not recoganized by the scene-builder tool.

please see the below code. HolderPane is a child class of AnchorPane, and here the children of HolderPane is hardcoded with the anchor values.

```
<HolderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" 
   minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="500.0" 
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
       <AnchorPane AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0 
          AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
       </AnchorPane>
   </children>
```